# PDF/A compliance with pdf metadata

Tags: hyperref, pdf, pdfx, hyperxmp

I am trying to create pdf/a-1b compliant pdf with the `\DocumentMetadata` and properly add the metadata. Firstly, I tried with `pdfx`, but the metadata was empty. My question is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632316/pdfa-compliance-vs-pdf-metadata-with-newtx), so I followed the advice and have this:

```
\DocumentMetadata{pdfstandard=A-1b, pdfversion=1.4, lang=en}
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={me},
    pdftitle={mytitle},
    pdfsubject={subject},
    pdfkeywords={key1, key2},
    pdfproducer=pdfTeX-1.40.25,
    pdfdate={\today},
    pdflang={en},
    pdfmetalang={en}
}
\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered=true, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=0}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\hypersetup{unicode}
\begin{document}

Contents of the document
\end{document}
```

Is this the right way of doing it? The metadata is filled and now I have two questions:

1. After each keyword, Adobe Acrobat Reader states a language tag, e.g. `key1; en; key2; en`, as `en` would be a keyword, which does not seem right?
2. One of the [online pdf/a validators](https://www.pdfen.com/pdf-a-validator) still reports that the metadata is either missing or corrupt.

Comment: the keywords looks ok in the xmp but yes adobe shows them rather curiously.  I can't see the error message from your validator, verapdf complains about dc:date (pdfdate key), imho wrongly but I will check.

Comment: ah, sorry I see the error with the date. You are using "\today" but the value must be given in ISO-format (see l3pdfmeta.pdf). At best simply leave it out, today's date is added automatically anyway.

Comment: As @UlrikeFischer noted, the string format in PDF/X metadata (XMP) has specific requirements, which often differ from what you would expect in ordinary text. Also, the escape characters of TeX are not escape characters in XMP (and vice-versa), but this is automatically handled by software. Package `hyperref` does a lot of the heavy lifting, even when the document contains no hyperlinks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Indeed, I removed the `pdfdate` key after I saw verapdf error. The online validator was not complaining after verapdf fixed the metadata, but when removing the date key, I still get the error that the file is not pdf/a compliant. I checked the metadata with `exiftool`, which seems to work ok, the only weird thing is that keywords are assigned to `Subject` field. Also the `Preview` on mac does not show the Author and any of the keywords.